# Distracting thing in PHP

Tags: php, html-entities

Im distracted with this thing in PHP. I have a search engine people search many things some times this value occurs "/" for example "She Doesn/'t Mind" . As im also using mod_rewrite so it seems like this "She doesn/'t mind" so Apache takes it as a directory :s and things don't work.

Please help me out.

Which function to use and where to avoid this ?

Comment: always encode your URL .

Comment: It looks like you need to reconfigure your `mod_rewrite` conditions/patterns.

Comment: distractions can be overcome with willpower

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) around the search in PHP.

For instance

```
$search = stripslashes( $_POST['search'] );
```

Comment: the problems occurs in apache before it reaches php

Comment: @andho without more information from the op this is the best I can do.